# pandas rowwise transformation with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, row, slice

I tinkered some ugly codes to deal with this but wanted to find out a pythonic way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'signal':[1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],'product':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],'price':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'price_B':[1,1,1,4,4,4,4,0,2,2,2,5,5,5,]})
```

I want to create the 'Price_B' column. for every 'product' subgroup, Price_B equals to Price if 'signal' is 1. Price_B equals previous row's Price if signal is 0. If the subgroup starts with a 0 'signal', then 'price_B' will be kept at 0 until 'signal' turns 1.

Here are what I wrote:

```
dfb = df.groupby('product').get_group('B')
for i in dfb.index:
    if dfb.loc[i, 'signal'] == 1:
        dfb.loc[i, 'test'] = dfb.loc[i, 'price']
    else:
        try:
            dfb.loc[i, 'test'] = dfb.loc[i - 1, 'test']
        except KeyError:
            dfb.loc[i, 'test'] = 0
```

I know these codes are not legal. Can someone help?

Comment: Your code inside the `for` loop is not properly indented.

Comment: oh yea. Just updated the for loop

Comment: Use .loc() List comprehension like in my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `pd.Series.where` to nullify data where signal is not `1`.  Then forward fill and fill na.

```
def f(d):
    dtype = d.price.dtype
    p = d.price.where(d.signal.eq(1))
    return p.ffill().fillna(0).astype(dtype)

df.assign(price_B=df.groupby('product', group_keys=False).apply(f))

    price  price_B product  signal
0       1        1       A       1
1       2        1       A       0
2       3        1       A       0
3       4        4       A       1
4       5        4       A       0
5       6        4       A       0
6       7        4       A       0
7       1        0       B       0
8       2        2       B       1
9       3        2       B       0
10      4        2       B       0
11      5        5       B       1
12      6        5       B       0
13      7        5       B       0
```

Comment: Hi, I wondered how to add an argument in the f(d) function and apply it to df?

Now f(d) only targets ['price'] column, but I wanted to make it dynamic and let the function target other columns such as ['price2']

Comment: hi @piRSquared - super like your answer. For "d.price.where(d.signal.eq(1))" , 'eq' only works on numeric fields. what do we do if 'signal' would have been character?

Answer (score 0):

```
df["price_B"]=[df.loc[i-1,"price_B"] if df.loc[i,"signal"]==0 else df.loc[i,"price"] for i in range(len(df["price"]))]

print(df)

    price  price_B product  signal
0       1        1       A       1
1       2        1       A       0
2       3        1       A       0
3       4        4       A       1
4       5        4       A       0
5       6        4       A       0
6       7        4       A       0
7       1        4       B       0
8       2        2       B       1
9       3        2       B       0
10      4        2       B       0
11      5        5       B       1
12      6        5       B       0
13      7        5       B       0
```